# jQuery wrap tr and div from ajax response

Tags: jquery

The ajax response contains html and it has two elements `tr` and `div`. I need to append `tr` to `table` and need to move `div` to other place. But apparently wrapping a `tr` and `div` together is only giving me `tr` (maybe because together they are not a valid html). How can I split them so that I have `tr` in one variable and `div` in other (I can use regex replace to split `tr` and `div` first and then wrap them separately, but regex are dangerous and not 100% accurate specially on html tags). Consider this:

```
var ajax_response = "<tr><td>Hello</td></tr><div>Move me</div>";
var $container = $(ajax_response).wrap("<div />").parent();
alert($container.html()); // this only has tr not div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is invalid HTML structure. The browser will move the div outside the table. Since only a `tr` is being appended the `div` will not be visible.

The only option is to move the div inside the td like this

```
var ajax_response  = $('<output/>').append('<tr><td>Hello<div>Move me</div></td></tr>');
var div = ajax_response.find('div').remove();
var tr = ajax_response.find('tr');
```

---

### Update

You can use [.parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) like this

```
var response = '<table>';
var response += ajax_response + '</table>';
var output = $.parseXML(response);
var div = $(output).find('div');
var tr = $(output).find('tr');
```

This works because parseXML creates a valid XML document. In order to create a valid XML it pushes the div outside the table which is why a `<table></table>` needs to be wrapped around the response. Then using jquery convert the XML document to jquery object and use find to get the required elements.

I hope this makes sense

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/jayude/edit?js,output**

Comment: Not working `$('<output/>').append` will validate the html and ignore div. Any jQuery method will do that. I think the only option is to do a javascript split.

Comment: I am sorry, the sample code did not reflect the suggestion I made. The div has to be moved inside the td, only then it would work. I updated the code now. Please check

Comment: I can not move `div` inside `td`. Its coming from ajax response and `div` appears after `tr`. Consider it a limitation I can't change.

Comment: @AamirAdnan: I found a way. Please check the answer and see if it works for you. One of the toughest problems I ever solved :D

Comment: Yup it works, Thanks! `parseXML` is the way to go. This problem was very tricky I know :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid HTML, so the div gets lost. You have to do some manual string parsing. This is very dangerous depending on your ajax response.

Consider this:

```
var ajax_response = "<tr><td>Hello</td></tr><div>Move me</div>";

// Split it on the div element
parts = ajax_response.split(/<div>/, 2);

// Add the div back to the element
parts[1] = '<div>' + parts[1];

// Create your jQuery objects, one for the tr and one for the div
var tr = $(parts[0]);
var div = $(parts[1]);
```

But, this is really bad because what happens if your ajax response is something like this:

```
var ajax_response = "<tr><td><div>Hello</div></td></tr><div>Move me</div>";
```

A response like this will break your code. It is very possible that the  element has a div inside it.

There is no good way to handle your situation so that it works in all cases. My suggestion is to see if you can change your ajax response so that it is jSon formatted or at the very least, has some type of separator that you can split on... Something that won't be repeated.

```
// This is better... Use a separator. 
// Something that won't get repeated like ||
var ajax_response = '<tr><td>Hello</td></tr>||<div>Move Me</div>';

// Split it
parts = ajax_response.split('||');

// Create your jQuery objects
var tr = $(parts[0]);
var div = $(parts[1]);
```

Even better is using jSon

```
// Make the ajax response be jSon
var ajax_response = '["<tr><td>Hello</td></tr>","<div>Move Me</div>"]';

// Parse the jSon
parts = JSON.parse(ajax_response);

// Create your jQuery objects, one for the tr and one for the div
var tr = $(parts[0]);
var div = $(parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant solution, but it will do the work to separate them without regex:

```
var arr = a.split('r><d'),
     tr = arr[0] += 'r>',
    div = arr[1] = '<d' + arr[1];
```

After this, you can append to the corresponding element.